# Zing Chart Stacked Graph

Tags: html, json, token, zingchart

I am using a Zing Chart Stacked Bar Graph. I'm loading data from an Oracle database to populate the graph. I have two stacks: Open and Closed. I want to show the numbers of Open documents to closed documents at the top of the stack as Open:Closed (ex. 5:303). I am able to get the numbers to print at the top of the individual stack (5 over top the closed bar, 303 over top the open bar) but I want to display them at the very top because if there is 1 open and 0 closed, the numbers overlap each other and is unable to be read. So, I have been looking at all of the JSON tokens that the Zing Charts offers and I haven't been able to find a way to grab each number (value) and display them together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access node values by both plot and node index. For example, `(%node-value)(0)(4)` would give you the value of the 5th node on the first plot.

Since a stacked bar graph is technically 2 plots, you could use the following tokens in your second (Open) plot:

`"text":"%node-value:(%node-value)(0)"`

A live example is below - run the snippet to see the chart.

```js
var myConfig = {
"graphset":[
    {
        "legend":{
            "margin-top":50,
            "background-color":"#FFFFFF",
            "border-color":"#CCCCCC",
            "shadow":false,
            "margin-right":10,
            "alpha":1
        },
        "border-color":"#cccccc",
        "series":[
            {
                "text":"Closed",
                "shadow-color":"#cccccc",
                "shadow-blur-y":1,
                "line-color":"#008000",
                "background-color":"#008000",
                "type":"bar",
                "values":[0,0,1,1,3,3,3,3,4,4],
                "shadow-alpha":1,
                "marker":{
                    "background-color-2":"#008000",
                    "background-color":"#008000"
                },
                "shadow":true,
                "background-color-2":"#008000",
                "shadow-distance":2,
                "shadow-blur-x":2
            },
            {
                "text":"Open",
                "shadow-color":"#cccccc",
                "shadow-blur-y":1,
                "line-color":"Orange",
                "background-color":"Orange",
                "type":"bar",
                "values":[3,6,8,8,83,94,96,102,297,303],
                "shadow-alpha":1,
                "marker":{
                    "background-color-2":"Orange",
                    "background-color":"Orange"
                },
                "shadow":true,
                "background-color-2":"Orange",
                "shadow-distance":2,
                "shadow-blur-x":2,
                "value-box":{
                    "font-size":14,
                    "font-color":"black",
                    "bold":true,
                    "font-family":"Consolas",
                    "placement":"top",
                    "type":"all",
                    "text":"%node-value:(%node-value)(0)"
                }
            }
        ],
        "scale-y":{
            "line-gap-size":0,
            "tick":{
                "line-gap-size":0,
                "line-color":"#cccccc",
                "line-width":1,
                "size":10
            },
            "line-color":"#cccccc",
            "bold":true,
            "item":{
                "font-size":12,
                "bold":true,
                "font-family":"Consolas",
                "color":"#333333"
            },
            "label":{
                "font-size":16,
                "margin-left":10,
                "text":"Count",
                "color":"#333333"
            },
            "line-width":2,
            "font-family":"Consolas",
            "color":"#333333"
        },
        "plotarea":{
            "margin-top":50,
            "margin-left":70,
            "margin-right":100,
            "margin-bottom":80
        },
        "scale-x":{
            "line-gap-size":0,
            "tick":{
                "line-gap-size":0,
                "line-color":"#999999",
                "line-width":1,
                "size":20
            },
            "font-size":8,
            "line-color":"#cccccc",
            "bold":true,
            "guide":{
                "line-width":1
            },
            "item":{
                "font-size":12,
                "bold":true,
                "font-family":"Consolas",
                "color":"#333333"
            },
            "label":{
                "padding-top":100,
                "font-size":16,
                "text":"Month",
                "color":"#333333"
            },
            "line-width":1,
            "font-family":"Consolas",
            "color":"#333333",
            "values":["Feb 2015","Mar 2015","Apr 2015","May 2015","Jun 2015","Jul 2015","Aug 2015","Sep 2015","Oct 2015","Nov 2015"]
        },
        "background-color":"WhiteSmoke",
        "border-width":1,
        "stacked":true,
        "lens":{
            "visible":true,
            "height":60,
            "width":60
        },
        "plot":{
            
        },
        "type":"bar",
        "title":{
            "background-color":"white",
            "border-color":"#cccccc",
            "border-width":1,
            "font-size":18,
            "bold":true,
            "text":"L2PRO-TRAVs (Updated: 17 Nov 2015, 13:08)",
            "font-family":"Consolas",
            "color":"#333333"
        }
    }
]
};
 
zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```